# How to implement SignalR chat application in cors WEB API2?

Tags: signalr, chatroom

I have a requirement to implement chat(one to one , group chat and file transfer) functionality. We are using separate solutions for UI(ASP.NET MVC) and WEB API2.   Can we implement the same via WEB API2 and ASP.NET mvc?

If any other solution please suggest.

Comment: Just google it..

Comment: Do you want to implement chat solution purely with WEB API2 and ASP.NET or Signalr ?

Comment: I have to implement chat application with WEB API2 with ASP.NET MVC